# Unique point in a Convex set

Tags: analysis

If C is a convex set in a plane how can I show that there is a unique point M such that d(A,M)=d(A,C) where A is an arbitrary point.

Comment: I tried to do it by contradiction, assuming M and M' be two such points then I get d(A,M)=d(A,M'). How to use the convexity now?

Comment: You probably want $C$ to be a *closed* convex set and $M$ to be a point in $C$. Then consider the definition of $d(A,C)$. What do you know about the minimizer of a convex function over a convex set?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have two minimal points $M$ and $M'$. Then consider the point $\frac{M+M'}{2}$. Prove that this point is in $C$. Prove that its distance from $A$ is less.